# htaccess if is file or if is directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to handle all files with the default handler, but not directories/subdirectories.
I've these without success:

```
<Files>
SetHandler default-handler
</Files>

<Files *>
SetHandler default-handler
</Files>


<Files "*">
SetHandler default-handler
</Files>
```

The last two both work, however accessing a directory will cause my 404 page to appear.

Comment: What exactly do you want to handle directories and subdirectories?

Comment: The default `Options All Indexes`